ESD Protection with USB_2.0 and STM32F103 Series Microcontroller
I want to use an STM32F103 Microcontroller and power it with USB + get some data from the Microcontroller via the USB D+/D- lines.
Now this is the refference design I came up with, using the AN4879 and AN5612 application note from ST.

As this is my first Project of using an USB Port on an PCB, I just want to verify that this is a valid protection for the Microcontroller pins.
I also want to exchange the ESDA7P60-1U1M, that is recommended for the circuit by ST, because I want to order it from JLCPCB and would prefer to stick to the basic components.
But this diode seems a bit special because I have not found one with the same characteristica.
Could you also give me some impression what are the important parameters of this diode?

Grounding the connector shield will improve things massively, as well as general EMI immunity and signal integrity.
Check the connector pinout: you seem to have displaced the USB net labels.
Check datasheet on the TVS: your schematic symbol shows no connection between left and right sides, and therefore no USB connectivity.
Often, connections are made through (underneath) the chip, using two pins in parallel.  They will therefore have the same net, not different nets.
There are some types with internal filtering e.g. USBUF01W6 and thus internal connection between pin pairs, which would use such a connection, hence checking the datasheet to be sure.
D1 is also redundant, if the array has a main clamp diode as the schematic suggests.
Layout is critical, with the GND pin needing a low impedance path to surrounding ground plane, and a bypass cap on VBUS (or joined to the internal power plane) doesn't hurt.  A 2-layer design is reasonable but 4 layers is easier to get right.

Now I see my misstake. The diodes are also parallel to the data lines and not in series as I thought before. My bad.
A 4 Layer design is already planned, because it also does not cost very much more.
I have attached a snippet of the corrected schematic below.

Corrected Schematic. DP and DM are net labels that are connected to the Microcontroller. schematic

@Cats in the updated schematic the diode VN is connected to VBUS and VP is connected to GND. That looks reversed and will cause the SRV05-4 to effectively short-out the VBUS supply.

The D and ID pins are also still crossed.

Technically the parts should work if you used the parts from a reference design. Also any ESD protector intended for USB use should work. JLCPCB must have at least one suitable part.
However they seem to be wired very randomly and that does not work. Please look at the reference design again to copy it correctly.

No it's not the datalines should attach to the SRV05 and not pass through:

Source: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/srv05-4-d.pdf


The diode in the schematics has 4 IOs to protect. This schematic adds two protections per wire. It's not a 2 IO passthrough chip.

That's true, but if the part has already been selected it wouldn't hurt to do this.

@VoltageSpike Will adding two protection diodes per wire double the Junction Capacitance between I/O Pins and GND, and is that likely to be significant in terms of signal distortion?

Now as you mentioned it, I saw some other designs, where the D-/D+ were just passed through the device. But honestly I don't understand how that's working at all. There is no connection from between thes IOS..

Some of ST's parts do that, but if the device supports it then you can use it that way. But for this one you won't get signals through if you use it like the OP is
